# Is there a Mac emulator for Ubuntu?

Tags: emulation

I want to get a program to run Mac programs on Ubuntu 14.04.  There is WINE for running Windows programs but I couldn't find a program to run Mac programs.

Answer (score 6):

Even though Ubuntu and OSX have similar bases (Linux & UNIX), emulation is surprisingly difficult; OSX applications run in a different display server with different display toolkits.  There was large motivation to run Windows applications on Linux, the same is not true of OSX, hence there isn't one (that's working and widespread).

You can check out [Darling](http://www.darlinghq.org/), which is an in-progress attempt at what you mention.  It's not usable, but it's cool to see how it's going.

Answer (score 5):

Apple is not friendly to people trying to run on non-approved hardware.  In fact, they actively discourage it.

I have OSX 10.9.3 running in vmware, and it was really a hassle to setup.  Still have poor sound quality, but have given up on that for the time being.  Can't even really remember how I got it going, but I believe I essentially started with a snow leopard install, and upgraded eventually to a clean mavericks.  One site to start from with information about this is [tonymacx86](http://www.tonymacx86.com/home.php)